# Rotate to opposite direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity2D
How to make game object to face opposite from the position of another game object?
I have a fish that is going always forward and randomly rotating to make semi random movement,
and i want that in range of player(shark) the fish change direction opposite to shark and start moving faster(trying to escape). I have speed increase already but i doknt know how to make the opposite direction.

```cs
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FishMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    int rotZ = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    Transform target;
    float speed;
    bool move=true;
    bool rotace = true;
    [SerializeField]
    int smerRotace;
    [SerializeField]
    float casRotace;
    float nula;
    [SerializeField]
    Transform shark;
    float fearRange=4;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

  
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        if (rotace)
        {
            rotace = false;
            smerRotace = Random.Range(-1, 2);
            if (smerRotace == 0) nula = 0.2f;
          


            Invoke("Rotace", Random.Range(3.0f*nula, 9.0f*nula));
            nula = 1;
        }
       
        
             
            rotZ += 2 * smerRotace;

        float distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, shark.position);
        if (distance < fearRange)
        {
            speed = 0.1f;
            
        

        }
        else
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ);
        }
       

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed);
        speed = 0.05f;


    }

    void Rotace()
    {
       rotace = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please proving full code including transform moving.

Comment: Posted full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice: at the part when I am saying to add/subtract 90 (you’ll know when you get there), try adding 90, if that doesn’t work, try subtracting 90 to get the right result.

To make it move fully the opposite direction, you should do a few things. First, I will tell you about `Mathf.Atan2(float y, float x)`. Atan2 is arctangent. Arctangent takes a position, and finds the amount of rotations to rotate at that object, in radians. Then, you would want to multiply by `Mathf.Rad2Deg`, or radians to degrees. It converts radians to degrees, which unity uses. Then, you would add some degrees to face the opposite direction.

Here is a way to make an object look away from the the mouse:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LookAtMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;

    Vector3 offset;
    Vector3 mousePosition;
    float rotation;
    void Update()
    {
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        offset = mousePosition - obj.transform.position;
        rotation = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation);
    }
}
```

Basically, the script gets the mouse position, and stores it in `mousePosition`. Then, it gets the offset of the mouse relative to `obj`. The rotation is the product of the arctangent of the offset and the amount of degrees in a radian (unity uses degrees, not radians), minus 90. Arctangent is 90 degrees off of the target, so people usually **add** 90 to get it to look at the target. **We are looking away from the target, so we subtract 90** to be 180 degrees away, or half way.

We would do the same thing for your script; here it is:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FishMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    int rotZ = 0;
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    float speed;
    bool move=true;
    bool rotace = true;
    [SerializeField] int smerRotace;
    [SerializeField] float casRotace;
    float nula;
    [SerializeField] Transform shark;
    float fearRange=4;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    Vector3 offset;
    float rotation;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (rotace)
        {
            rotace = false;
            smerRotace = Random.Range(-1, 2);
            if (smerRotace == 0) nula = 0.2f;
            Invoke("Rotace", Random.Range(3.0f*nula, 9.0f*nula));
            nula = 1;
        }
        rotZ += 2 * smerRotace;
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, shark.position);
        if (distance < fearRange)
        {
            speed = 0.1f;
            offset = transform.position - shark.transform.position;
            rotation = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ);
        }
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed);
        speed = 0.05f;
    }
    void Rotace()
    {
       rotace = true;
    }
}
```

Tell me in the comments if it works or if it doesn't work.

Comment: I tryied this code and the fish was always facing the shark so i change in rotation to -90f and now its working, thank you so much. <3

Comment: @DixisCZ oops I just have mixed it up.